# Need regular expression to extract month,day,time i.e Sep 14 16:08

Tags: c#, regex

yes this is C#. The script is reading a txt file containing the line string.

Giving the string below I need to be able to extract the month,day and time such as "Sep 14 16:08":

-rw-r--r-- 1 user001 user001 0 Sep 14 16:08 20180913/labc/0/20180913_02300

I have researched and found the following:

```
@"(?i)([\d]{1,2}(\s)?(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))(\s)?[\d]{1,2}");
@"(?i)([\d]{1,2}(\s)?(January|Jan|February|feb|March|mar|April|Apr|May|June|July|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec))
(January|Jan|February|feb|March|mar|April|Apr|May|June|July|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec)(\s)?[\d]{1,2}");
(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}
```

but I can't seem to put together something that will extract "Month Day XX:XX"

Thank you all

Comment: Are you looking for the date only in that example string?

Comment: Better would be to stat the file directly, and use the system structures to get the data rather than parsing the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: The `@"..."` pattern strongly suggests this is C# code. If your program is running on a Linux box, @Tanktalus's suggestion is right: Get the file stats directly rather than trying to parse the output of `ls`. But if your code is running on Windows, and/or you're just consuming text outputted by something outside your control, like a remote script, you'll have to use some kind of regex parsing like this. Can you tell us more about your scenario so we can provide answers closer to your needs?

Comment: yes this is C#. The script is reading a txt file containing the line string.

Comment: to add to @Tanktalus comment if it's to parse ls output, it's not always consustent, for older dates hour:minutes can be replaced with year, also `LANG` environment variable should be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten you RegEx, so that it matches what you want:

```
(?:(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s\d{4}
```

What it does is first find the month,

then a Space followed by one or two digits

then a Space followed by one or two digits

then a colon followed by one or two digits

then a Space followed by four digits.

You can try it out [here](http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/RegExBuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ranges to match the days and the time. Note that the match  does not validate the date itself.

`\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]) (?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5]?[0-9])\b`

That would match

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` Match a month followed by a whitespace
- `(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])` Match a day followed by a whitespace
- `(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5]?[0-9])` Match the time
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqJP6k/1)